# How to revert the following command for PATH?

Tags: bash, shell, path, terminal, command

I typed the following command in terminal and would like to reverse it.
I am using Mac 10.9

```
sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/mysql/bin > /etc/paths.d/mysql'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had an `/etc/paths.d/mysql` existing before, then restore it from your backups.

If you did not have an `/etc/paths.d/mysql` file before, then delete it.

Comment: Well, you created the file with `sudo`, which means it's owned by root. So `sudo rm /etc/paths.d/mysql` should do it.